# Is there a way to show a 1:1 scale preview/secondary view?

Tags: gimp

When you're zoomed in editing something very small (like an icon), it's hard to tell what it looks like at 1:1.  Is there any way to avoid having to constantly zoom from 1:1 to your editing zoom level?

The OLD version (as in, Windows XP old) of a paint program named Paint Shop Pro (5-6) allowed this by just letting you have multiple window views of the same image. What's the best Gimp solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a new view of our canvas with *View > New View*. On any of views the zoom factor can be adapted to convenient values for easy switching between different zoom levels.

When in multi-windowed mode these views can also be displayed next to each other:

[image]

Comment: Forgot there was a multi window mode!

Answer (score 3):

It's usually not 1:1 views, but may be useful for finding your way around a zoomed-in image:

You can add a [Navigation Dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-navigation-dialog.html) anywhere in your docks. This will display your image with a highlighted area indicating the part of the image that's visible in the active image window or tab.

[image: GIMP Navigation Dialog]

You can drag this frame to move around in your image, and the dialog also has got zoom controls to control the zoom level of the image window/tab.

Also, in the lower right corner of an image window/tab, there's a small four-way cross that opens a similar dialog with that highlighted area, but sans the zoom feature.

[image: GIMP Navigation popup]

Comment: I've been using GIMP for years and never noticed this feature!

Comment: You do realize that I just summarized the GIMP user manual page about that dialog, and even took the images directly from there, right?